# how to create a git changelog containing the names of all the merged branches since a commit

Tags: git, changelog

Assuming that I have multiple branches spawn from branch `stable`, each one containing a fix or a feature (or whatever):

```
stable--------
|\            \
| |           |
| |           |
| *fix-1234   *feature-6789
|/            /
stable--------
```

When everything is merged back to `stable` I want to create a changelog containing the names of all branches that merged to `stable` since a given commit. For the above example, that would be:

```
fix-1234 <date> <user>
feature-6789 <date> <user>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. Branches can be removed.

Comment: I do not want to remove them, but to create a changelog with the history of branch names that merged into `stable`.

Comment: "I do not want to remove them", no, but branches can be deleted. Do you keep your branches around after you've merged them into stable. Either your branches have to be kept around, or you have to grab the branch names from the merge commit messages.

Comment: OK, I see. Assume that I keep my branches (at least until create the changelog)

Comment: Try `git branch --merged stable`

Comment: Thank you. This might be, can I narrow this list since a given commit to ensure that this can drive me to the solution?